# C# Regex to get the comments block out of pl/sql code

Tags: c#, regex, parsing, plsql

i want to extract the comments out of a string as a block.

e.g. I have a PL/SQL code as:

> ```
> --comment1
> select * from t_table;
> --i want comment 2;
> /*i want comment
> 3 */
> --i want comment 4
> OPEN data_cur;
> ```

Here, i want all the single line and multiline comments before OPEN data_cur; but after 
select * from t_table;

i.e. i want a full comment block between two PL/SQL statements.

i want the regex to match the string and form the groups as:

1. SQL statement
2. whole comment block

Can it be done using any regex?

Comment: I have modified the regex as requested

Comment: this regex is not working properly if there is no statement before any type of comments. i.e. if the comment comes as a first statement.

Comment: Regex modified as requested: group1 is o or n comments (only for the first match), group2 is statement, group3 is 0 or n comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
(?ms)^\s*([^\-/\s][^;]+;)((?:(?:\s+/\*(?:.(?!\*/))+.\*/)|(?:\s+\-\-[^\r\n]+))*)
```

should do it nicely.
(Note: `(?ms)` is the way in Java to specify a "multi-line" "dot-all" mode, but I have [tested in on RETester](http://regexlib.com/RETester.aspx) and it works)

It can detect 0 or more comments after the `select`.
Multi line comments are accepted between `/*` and `*/` because of the use of a [positive lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) `(?:.(?!\*/))+` in a non-capturing group

Update: modified it to detect any "non-comment" line before 0 or many comments.

---

To detect comment1, then statement, then comments:

```
(?ms)((?:(?:\s+/\*(?:.(?!\*/))+.\*/)|(?:\s+\-\-[^\r\n]+))*)\s*^\s*([^\-/\s][^;]+;)((?:(?:\s+/\*(?:.(?!\*/))+.\*/)|(?:\s+\-\-[^\r\n]+))*)
```

Note: I have update in both regexps (the one in the beginning and this one) the statement detection part:

```
\s*([^\-/][^;]+;)
```

to

```
\s*([^\-/\s][^;]+;)
```

Note bis: only the first "`comments - statement - comments`" will be detected.
The next blocks will also be detected, but only as : "`statement - comments`", then "`statement - comments`", and so on. (the comments above a statement are part of the comments *below* the *previous* statement)

Comment: thanks. but it should work for all statements in pl/sql and not just for select.

Comment: If i wan the group as:
1. Comment block
2. SQL Statements
then what shall i do? i tried changing the sequence as well as back reference to ?<! but it didnt work. please help.